# What does "throw back" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, american-english, slang

In this sentence:

> I've throw back a lot of orange juice.

What does to “*throw back* (orange juice)” mean?

Comment: In that particular tense, people would say *thrown*, not *throw*.  A person can *throw back* juice, or any other drink.  If they have done it already, then they have *thrown back* some before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In that particular sentence, it means *drunk*.

In that the person has "thrown back" a lot of orange juice, thrown the juice to the back of their throat, i.e. tipped their head back and drunk the juice.

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Yes, it was a bit overly explained.  The key difference between saying drunk the juice, and using the phrase *thrown back* is an indication that it was done quickly.

Comment: @yozloy: Quite alright, I think the usual crowd must be off this weekend, otherwise there would probably be a better answer!

Answer (score 3):

I believe an alternate, perhaps British term, is to "knock back" (usually a drink).

Answer (score 3):

1. *Throw back* or *thrown* back is definitely a reference to consuming a beverage.
2. It is also a loose reference to an old reference of the past... "That old song is a throw back".
3. However, if used by a younger person — say, in a text reference —, it is a common vernacular for paying due deference to a time gone past; remembering nostalgically. For example, teens will send me photos from their Instagram accounts that we had taken when they were younger.  Swimming, crafting, painting, water balloon fights etc. The hash tag is always  #tbtp which is throwing it back to... and my name.  I'm an old gal so it always makes my day!