# when you say "throw back" some drinks, is the word replaceable with "gulp"?

Tags: idioms

This is the whole sentence from the article:

"R went to the bar, where he and other friends threw back drinks, the photos show."

Comment: Which article? Can you provide the source, please? Why the need for anonymity "R"? Is that the original sentence? "Throw back" is not really one word, it is an idiom.

Comment: Related: [What does “throw back” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/what-does-throw-back-mean)

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. A gulp on its own implies a single large swallow, whereas "throw back" implies several swallows in a row (possibly even finishing the drink). I would say "gulp down" "chug" or "chug down" are interchangeable with "throw back".

Comment: Not according to [M-W](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/throw-back)

Comment: MW defines throw back as "drink quickly" or "in one swallow". When you drink something quickly, you usually have to swallow many times (especially if its a full beer). If its a smaller drink, like a shot of whiskey, then you can " throw it back" in one swallow.

Comment: When you here he threw back his drink I imaging the cowpoke at the bar slammin' a full shot of redeye in one motion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a definition for **throw back** which says

> To drink something quickly, usually swallowing it all at once.

- [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/throw-back)

Are the two words 100% interchangeable? No.  But there's definitely some overlap in their definitions (mostly the drinking quickly). One situation where they differ is that *gulping* is used to convey both eating/drinking quickly and *the audible sounds associated with it*:

> swallow (drink or food) quickly or in large mouthfuls, often audibly.

- [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=define%20gulp)